# MySQL: Offset и Limit как правильно составить запрос

Tags: mysql, node.js, mysql-workbench

Допустим есть таблица `users` в которой **40** записей

Тогда запрос:

```
SELECT id, firstname, lastname, score FROM users ORDER BY somethink DESC LIMIT 30 OFFSET 0
```

вернет первые 30 записей, как и ожидается, но запрос:

```
SELECT id, firstname, lastname, score FROM users ORDER BY somethink DESC LIMIT 30 OFFSET 20
```

вернет не последние **20** записей, а последние **30**.

Как сделать так, чтобы возвращалось не больше **30** записей, но если должно быть выведено меньше **30**, то выводилось именно столько?

P.S. Проблема в том, что `LIMIT` выставляется "железно" и если запись должна быть в `OFFSET`, но должно вернуться записей меньше, чем указано в `LIMIT`, запись возвращается, чтоб в результате было столько записей, сколько указано в `LIMIT`

Comment: Что-то по Вашему описанию проблема не вопроизводится: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/be7f03/1